# drop some rows with more that a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like below:

```
       start  start_interaction
0     710000          224180000
1     710000               3445
2     715000             760000
3     755000             7603
4     755000             870000
..       ...                ...
149  1840000            1935000
150  1840000            1980000
```

and I have a list like below:

```
myList=[(710000,3445),(755000,7603) ,(77700,234)]
```

so I need to delete the rows whose the first element in tuple that in `myList`  should be in the `start` column  and the second element in my tuple  should be in `start_interaction` column
And the end result that I want is like below:

```
start  start_interaction
0     710000          224180000
2     715000             760000
4     755000             870000
..       ...                ...
149  1840000            1935000
150  1840000            1980000
```

so please tell me how can I do it. thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You can craft a dataframe from your list, perform a left [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with `indicator=True` and use the `left_only` indicator to build a boolean array. Finally slice the original dataframe:

```
cols = list(df.columns) # subset here if needed
df2 = pd.DataFrame(myList, columns=cols)

mask = (df.merge(df2, on=cols, how='left', indicator=True)
        ['_merge'].eq('left_only').values # getting the values as the new index
                                          # is no longer aligned
        )

out = df[mask]
```

output:

```
       start  start_interaction
0     710000          224180000
2     715000             760000
4     755000             870000
149  1840000            1935000
150  1840000            1980000
```

Comment: have you spotted anything incorrect with this solution?

Comment: Not sure who you are asking that and I didn't downvote yet but -3 net vote on the question might be something to think over. Also you didn't explain why you are using `.values` for the mask.

Comment: I strongly disagree with your first sentence and I already downvoted the question. I can't read their minds through text and edit to include their attempts. For the record, I didn't downvote any of the answers here.

Comment: @neither Honestly, most of the times (in pandas at least) the attempt is irrelevant, no need to have a useless bit of code (most of the time based on loops) if you'll have to dump it anyway and rewrite all for an efficient solution

Answer (score -1):

not the most elegant maybe, but it works

```
df = df[[not(x) for x in [any([(row[1].start==x[0]) &(row[1].start_intercation==x[1]) for x in myList]) for row in df.iterrows()]]]
```

An explanation:
The following row checks whether the specific line "start" matches the first element of the tuple, and that "start_interaction" matches the 2nd object for any tuple in the list.

```
 [any([(row[1].start==x[0]) &(row[1].start_intercation==x[1]) for x in myList]]
```

the we filter df for the rows that does not meet this condition (no match in any item in the list.
we do that by filtering df for rows that does not meet the above condition:

```
df = df[[not(x) for x in cond]]
```

where `cond` is the condition above

Comment: I didn't downvote but instead of claiming nonelegantness of your answer, why not explain what it does how it does? But if you say that "the question asker didn't show any attempt at all, why should I attempt to explain my answer", that's perfectly understandable. I'd like to upvote if that's the case.